# JQUERY - Scrollable website

Tags: jquery, css, scrollable

Here is my challenge -

I have a website http://www.jodsn.com - On the homepage there are 2 buttons [VIEW MY WORK] and [VIEW MY SKILLSETS].

When you click on each button I want to slide out the default page and slide in either the work page or the skills page.

I don't think Arial Flesler's .ScrollTo will work because that seems to target elements that are already loaded on the page. If I am wrong then please correct me.

How would I accomplish this task in JQUERY?

Answer (score 0):

Why not position a div with an absolute position of top: -(height of div); then use scrollTo.

Then use jquery to load the page at any anchor you want.

Comment: I will be loading different background into the body as well as a lot og graphics for each page. I will not want to have to load all that in one shot. But if that is the only way then so be it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's scroll functions inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` function.

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   //Place .scrollTo code here.
});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am great at css / html and only a month into JQUERY.

Comment: I've edited the answer. The idea is that you should use DOM related functions inside a function passed as parameter to the ready method. This basically means "execute this code after the DOM is loaded" (all markup, not necessarily images and such).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have something that vaguely operates like a tabbed interface, with each tab being loaded via ajax and displayed with animation.

You can certainly do something plain with plugins like jqueryui, but for something that fits the style of your site, I'd go full custom. Start with this to load the content and then do something with it:

```
$.ajax('Skills.aspx', { 
  dataType: 'html'
  success: function(data){ 

    $('#container') // something to hold your content
      .slideUp(400, function(){   // hide existing content
        $(this).empty() // and remove it
        .append(data)   // append new content
        .slideDown();   // and show it
      });

  }
});
```

Again, that's just to get you started. If the content is lightweight, you could load it all from the server and skip the AJAX stuff altogether.

Comment: I will try this out for size. I have not worked much with .ajax but I will do some googling to troubleshoot. I will get back with some results soon. ( :

Comment: I am trying to wrap my brain around this and I think you are leaving out some details. I want to apply this to a the [VIEW MY WORK] button on my default.aspx. When you click it I want to slide out that page to the left and slide in my work.aspx page from the right. They are both asp.net child pages and I will need to grab all the content so it renders properly on the server...maybe you see it more clearly but I cannot grasp your solution to know how to apply it...lol.